# What did the sign say?

Tags: looper

At one point in Looper, someone comes out of the crops in the dark and walks towards the woman.  Joe jumps out to save her to find that the person isn't a threat and has a sign on them.  I didn't catch what the sign said.  What did it say?

Comment: But what does he mean by Muwte ? Is it short for "Me With" ?

Comment: Muwte = mute, explaining why the guy didn't speak up. Did the sign say deaf too?.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having seen the movie a second time, here's the text of the sign:

```
PLEASE HELP MUWTE
FOOD & GOD
BLESS YOU
```

Once Young Joe saw the sign, he just gestured for the vagrant to leave, instead of shooting him.